# Apply borders to all fields and labels in a form

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I need to style a bootstrap 3 form such as there is a border around each form field and label. Something like this -

[image: Borders around fields]

I am not able to make out how to go about doing this. Here is my attempt to achieve this (Please expand the output so that you see 2 columns in each row) -

https://jsfiddle.net/yy7ddtby/15/

```css
.custom-label {
  line-height: 3.3em !important;
}

.label-size {
  /*font-size: 10px;*/
  line-height: 2.1em;
  /*padding-right:0px;
   width: 10%;*/
}

.border {
  color: #555;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 1px;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">

  <form>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="name" class="col-md-4 label-size custom-label border">Name</label>
          <div class="col-md-8 border">
            <input type="text" id="name" class="form-control input-field">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="gender" class="col-md-4  label-size custom-label  border">Gender</label>
          <div class="col-md-8  border">
            <select id="gender" class="form-control input-field">
              <option value="Male">Male</option>
              <option value="Female">Female</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="col-md-4  label-size custom-label">Functions</label>
          <div class="checkbox col-md-8 label-size">
            <label>
                  <input type="checkbox" id="Func1"> Func1</label>
            <label>
                  <input type="checkbox" id="Func2">Func2</label>
            <label>
                  <input type="checkbox" id="Func3">Func3</label>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="country" class="col-md-4  label-size custom-label">Country</label>
          <div class="col-md-8">
            <select id="country" class="form-control input-field">
              <option>Select</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="options" class="col-md-4 label-size custom-label">Options</label>
          <div class="col-md-8">
            <select id="options" class="form-control input-field">
              <option>Select</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="addr" class="col-md-4 label-size custom-label">ADDR</label>
          <div class="col-md-8">
            <input type="text" id="addr" class="form-control input-field">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="author" class="col-md-4  label-size custom-label">Author</label>
          <div class="col-md-8">
            <input type="text" id="author" class="form-control input-field">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="range1" class="col-md-4  label-size custom-label">Range1</label>
          <div class="col-md-3">
            <input type="text" id="range1" class="form-control input-field">
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-2">
            to
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-3">
            <input type="text" id="range2" class="form-control input-field">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="ip" class="col-md-4 label-size custom-label">IP</label>
          <div class="col-md-8">
            <input type="text" id="ip" class="form-control input-field">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>



  </form>

</div>
```

I have tried to style the first row using a custom CSS called border. However, it doesn't look the way I want it to. The border it generates is quite untidy and not the way in the image.

How can I go about achieving the expected UI with borders?

Answer (score 0):

I would actually give the entire row the border, then use left/right borders on the form elements to divide them up.

Here's the basic idea:

```
.row {
  border: 2px solid black;
}

.form-group > label {
  border-right: 2px solid black;
}

input {
  border-right: 2px solid black;
}
```

[revised demo](https://jsfiddle.net/yy7ddtby/17/)

Comment: Thank you very much for sharing the revised demo. How can I get rid of spaces between rows and also not show two overlapping lines? For instance, there is a space between 'Name' and 'Functions' rows. Also, need to have a border before 2nd label in a row, example, before 'Gender', 'Country' etc.

Comment: Thank you Michael_B. I'll give it a try and get back with updated fiddle.